# sql squery writing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I wanted to run the same query on multiple databases using a while loop.

1. I created a table with the name '@database' and added the names of the database that I want to traverse through in  it
2. used while loop to traverse through databases names to run that particular query in each database

It didn't work.(it's running twice for the database which has been selected on the left dropdown of SQL management studio )

Tables in both databases are the same.

```
DECLARE @database TABLE (id INT,name varchar(50))

insert into @database values (1, 'Databse_one'), (2, 'Database_two')

DECLARE @cnt INT =2, @int INT=1,@dbname NVARCHAR(MAX)

while(@int <=@cnt)

 begin

select @dbname='use '+name from @database
where id=@int

EXEC sp_sqlexec @dbname
select top 10 db_name() DB_NAME, req_number, record Type,order_date from ORDER_DOCUMENT order by order_date desc

set @int = @int+1

end
```

Comment: what does `but it didn't work.` mean ? Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: The syntax highlighing alone shows you have syntax errors...

Comment: Also, `sp_sqlexec` really shouldn't be used anymore; if I recall correctly it was for SQL Server 2000 or even older databases. You should be using `sys.sp_executesql`.

Comment: its running for only that database which has been selected on the left dropdown of SQL management studio

Comment: @Larnu it's working but I'm not getting the desired output . Loop is running on the same database twice

Comment: That query won't run at all, @xyz , as I said, it has syntax errors.

Comment: @Larnu corrected the above mentioned mistake still getting same output ...running on same database twice

Comment: What procedure is `sp_sqlexec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't work like that even after you corrected the typos you already have. After use dbName, it would require a GO or be that in a different batch on the same connection. Instead you could write that as:

```
DECLARE @database TABLE(id INT, name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @database VALUES(1, 'Databse_one'), (2, 'Database_two');
DECLARE @cnt INT=2, @int INT=1, @dbname NVARCHAR(MAX);
WHILE(@int<=@cnt)BEGIN
    SELECT @dbname=name FROM @database WHERE id=@int;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql=N'select top(10) '''+@dbname+N''',req_number, record Type,order_date from '+QUOTENAME(@dbname)+N'.dbo.ORDER_DOCUMENT order by order_date desc;';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt=@sql;
    SET @int=@int+1;
END;
```

Comment: can you write the value of set @sql for the 1st iteration

Comment: Yes, you can put a: Print @sql there to see it yourself. It is something like: select top(10) 'databse_one',req_number, record Type,order_date from databse_one.dbo.ORDER_DOCUMENT order by order_date desc;

Answer (score 0):

`USE` doesn't work here, because the dynamic batch is a different scope. You would need to put the whole `SELECT` into the dynamic SQL.

But you don't need a `WHILE` at all. Just create one big `UNION ALL` query and run it.

```sql
DECLARE @database TABLE(name sysname);
INSERT INTO @database(name) VALUES(1, );

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT *
FROM (
' + STRING_AGG(CAST('
    SELECT TOP (10) 
      ' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ' DB_NAME,
      req_number,
      record Type,
      order_date
    FROM ' + + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '..ORDER_DOCUMENT
    ORDER BY
      order_date DESC
'  AS nvarchar(max)), '
') + '
);
'

FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name IN ('Databse_one', 'Database_two');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Alternatively if you want separate `SELECT` statements then remove the `UNION ALL`

```sql
DECLARE @database TABLE(name sysname);
INSERT INTO @database(name) VALUES(1, );

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT TOP (10) 
  ' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ' DB_NAME,
  req_number,
  record Type,
  order_date
FROM ' + + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '..ORDER_DOCUMENT
ORDER BY
  order_date DESC;
'  AS nvarchar(max)), '
')

FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name IN ('Databse_one', 'Database_two');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: the condition was that i have to use loops

Comment: Use the best tool for the job. A `WHILE` loop is not a good idea, it's really slow and difficult to code.